# In my react native app I have a button to connect twitter account I just want to get the persons username upon logingin through this button

Tags: twitter

In my react native app I have a button to connect twitter account I just want to get the persons username upon logingin through this button.
Please guide me what is the best way to do it.
just want to get username of the twitter account